# Configuring IPv6 to expose local device(s) to the internet

Tags: ipv6

I am trying to expose a local client to the net to host a website. I am struggling to understand IPv6.

Current setup:

```
ISP --> bridged ISP router --> TP-Link router --> LAN
```

I've configured the TP-Link router to use IPv6.
In the router's menu I see:

The "global address" under "IPv6/WAN" is

```
XXXX:YYY:ZZZ:aaa:RRRR:TTTT:UUUU:VVVV
```

The "LAN IPv6 address" under "IPv6/LAN" is

```
XXXX:YYE:ZZZ:aaa:<some local address>
```

My questions:

- What is the difference? I thought XXXX:YYY:ZZZ are assigned to my own network. "LAN" subtitle says "Configure the LAN IPv6 address of the
  router.". What is a LAN address? Why is it almost, but not quite the
  same as the router address? Compare YYY wiht YYE. I expected it to be
  the same since the router's address is the entry point to my local
  network.
- I am not sure if my devices are already exposed or not. If not, what do I have to do to expose a single device? I have also not seen any port related setting, but then how do I only publish one app listening on say port 8080, but not all from the device)?

Comment: Did your computer get an IPv6 address? Did you try connecting to it?

Comment: Both my computer and my raspberry pi have IPv6 addresses. All of the format containg YYK, so not the router's ipv6. I can ping both from https://dnschecker.org/ping-ipv6.php with their ips.

Comment: It sounds like you are already done "configuring".

Comment: I have the feeling that my setup is not ipv6 ready. I had an old setup with traefik reverse proxy running docker apps, that I wanted to "check again". I think there is the problem.

Comment: What does that have to do with your IPv6 connectivity? This is getting really confusing now.

Comment: Well. First, I still don't understand quetsion number 1. Second, the title says "expose devices" but what I meant was apps on that device. This is still not working. Hence my thought about docker related issues.

Comment: Your first question? That is just how IP works, both IPv4 and IPv6. Different physical networks are in different IP subnets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129335/discussion-between-user2366975-and-michael-hampton).

Answer (score 2):

Most traffic through an IPv6 router has a destination address *not* on the router's interfaces, but to other hosts in subnets delegated to it. IP forwarding happens as usual. IPv4 used to work this way, but NAT is so pervasive public addresses on every host seems alien to many people.

Say you are delegated `2001:db8:2106::/48`. A service provider should route all of it to you. Via your router, but how will the ISP identify your router separate from your network? Assign an IP address of course, say `2001:db8:c::954c:5cc7:7aeb:ec1d`. Such a WAN address is for the ISP's convenience, it does not need to be related to your nets at all.

Allow access to hosts on your network by firewall configuration.  If the application host is `2001:db8:2106:5821::443`, allow https/tcp to that IP. Any firewall worth using can filter by layer 4 ports. The firewall rules can be relatively straightforward, as unlike with NAT the destination IP is the host of interest, no port forwarding required.